# Python TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' on scikit load_boston data

Tags: python, typeerror

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' on load_boston data

I have tried `boston.iloc` and `boston.loc` and got Attribute Error: iloc

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
boston = load_boston()
print(boston.data.shape)
print("Data shape: {}".format(boston.data.shape))
print('The first few lines of data: {}'.format(boston.data[0:5,:]))
m = len(boston)
X = boston[:,0]
y = boston[:,1]

print("Number of examples: {}".format(m))
print("Shape of data     : {}".format(X.shape))
print("Shape of labels   : {}".format(y.shape))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: To get a regression model going using sklearn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `print(boston.keys())`, you will get the output

```
>>> print(boston.keys())
dict_keys(['data', 'target', 'feature_names', 'DESCR', 'filename'])
```

You should convert the data into a `DataFrame` first with `bos = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)` and it looks like:

```
>>> bos = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)
>>> print(bos.head())
        0     1     2    3      4      5     6       7    8      9     10      11    12
0  0.00632  18.0  2.31  0.0  0.538  6.575  65.2  4.0900  1.0  296.0  15.3  396.90  4.98
1  0.02731   0.0  7.07  0.0  0.469  6.421  78.9  4.9671  2.0  242.0  17.8  396.90  9.14
2  0.02729   0.0  7.07  0.0  0.469  7.185  61.1  4.9671  2.0  242.0  17.8  392.83  4.03
3  0.03237   0.0  2.18  0.0  0.458  6.998  45.8  6.0622  3.0  222.0  18.7  394.63  2.94
4  0.06905   0.0  2.18  0.0  0.458  7.147  54.2  6.0622  3.0  222.0  18.7  396.90  5.33
```

You may then wonder why is the column only showing its index and not its names. It turns out the column names is not directly embedded, and recall that we have the list of the column names. So, let’s convert the index to the column names:

```
bos.columns = boston.feature_names
print(bos.head())
```

which gives the output:

```
>>> print(bos.head())
      CRIM    ZN  INDUS  CHAS    NOX     RM   AGE     DIS  RAD    TAX  PTRATIO       B  LSTAT
0  0.00632  18.0   2.31   0.0  0.538  6.575  65.2  4.0900  1.0  296.0     15.3  396.90   4.98
1  0.02731   0.0   7.07   0.0  0.469  6.421  78.9  4.9671  2.0  242.0     17.8  396.90   9.14
2  0.02729   0.0   7.07   0.0  0.469  7.185  61.1  4.9671  2.0  242.0     17.8  392.83   4.03
3  0.03237   0.0   2.18   0.0  0.458  6.998  45.8  6.0622  3.0  222.0     18.7  394.63   2.94
4  0.06905   0.0   2.18   0.0  0.458  7.147  54.2  6.0622  3.0  222.0     18.7  396.90   5.33
```

Then I believe that you want the `PRICE` as your `y`:

```
bos['PRICE'] = boston.target
print(bos.head())
```

which has the output

```
>>> print(bos.head())
      CRIM    ZN  INDUS  CHAS    NOX     RM   AGE     DIS  RAD    TAX  PTRATIO       B  LSTAT  PRICE
0  0.00632  18.0   2.31   0.0  0.538  6.575  65.2  4.0900  1.0  296.0     15.3  396.90   4.98   24.0
1  0.02731   0.0   7.07   0.0  0.469  6.421  78.9  4.9671  2.0  242.0     17.8  396.90   9.14   21.6
2  0.02729   0.0   7.07   0.0  0.469  7.185  61.1  4.9671  2.0  242.0     17.8  392.83   4.03   34.7
3  0.03237   0.0   2.18   0.0  0.458  6.998  45.8  6.0622  3.0  222.0     18.7  394.63   2.94   33.4
4  0.06905   0.0   2.18   0.0  0.458  7.147  54.2  6.0622  3.0  222.0     18.7  396.90   5.33   36.2
```

Then finally split your dataset into `X` and `Yy:

```
X = bos.drop('PRICE', axis = 1)
y = bos['PRICE']
```

The next part is regression, but first split the data further into training and test sets:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 5)
```

You can print out the shapes as follows:

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(Y_train.shape)
print(Y_test.shape)
```

And finally fit the linear model:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train, Y_train)

Y_pred = lm.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Any idea how I can run 100 trials on that and graph the mean square error?

Comment: @NinJesus Your'e welcome! :) Do up vote and mark the answer as completed/closed if you find it helpful. As for your second question above, I shall not answer here as typically questions on this site are meant for a single problem, and if you have more than one problems which are independent, do post them in a separate question. In the mean time, perhaps you can take a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html and consider saving the outputs for each trial in a dataframe for plotting. Hope that helps!